# How to compile and run this code without using erlang shell

Tags: shell, compilation, erlang, erlang-shell

### How to compile and run this code without using erlang shell

I have the following code in erlang which gives solutions to the n-queens problem. It takes number of queens as argument. The program runs successfully on erl shell. But I need to run this program without shell on linux terminal so that I can use the 'time' command to measure execution time of the program.

```
    -module(queen).
-export([queen/1]).

queen(N) ->
    IJ = [{I, J} || I <- lists:seq(1, N), J <- lists:seq(1, N)],
    lists:foreach(fun({I, J}) -> put_data(I, J, true) end, IJ),
    solve(N, 1, [], 0).

solve(N, J, Board, Count) when N < J ->
    print(N, Board),
    Count + 1;
solve(N, J, Board, Count) ->
    F = fun(I, Cnt) ->
            case get_data(I, J) of
                true  ->
                    put_data(I, J, false),
                    Cnt2 = solve(N, J+1, [I|Board], Cnt),
                    put_data(I, J, true),
                    Cnt2;
                false -> Cnt
            end
        end,
    lists:foldl(F, Count, lists:seq(1, N)).

put_data(I, J, Bool) ->
    put({row, I  }, Bool),
    put({add, I+J}, Bool),
    put({sub, I-J}, Bool).

get_data(I, J) ->
    get({row, I}) andalso get({add, I+J}) andalso get({sub, I-J}).

print(N, Board) ->
    Frame = "+-" ++ string:copies("--", N) ++ "+",
    io:format("~s~n", [Frame]),
    lists:foreach(fun(I) -> print_line(N, I) end, Board),
    io:format("~s~n", [Frame]).

print_line(N, I) ->
    F = fun(X, S) when X == I -> "Q " ++ S;
           (_, S)             -> ". " ++ S
        end,
    Line = lists:foldl(F, "", lists:seq(1, N)),
    io:format("| ~s|~n", [Line]).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [timer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#tc-1) module to check speed of execution:

```
{Time, Value} = timer:tc(queen, queen, [N])
```

Or you can transform you code to escript:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript

-mode(native). %% to fun faster

main([NStr]) ->
    N = list_to_integer(NStr),
    IJ = [{I, J} || I <- lists:seq(1, N), J <- lists:seq(1, N)],
    lists:foreach(fun({I, J}) -> put_data(I, J, true) end, IJ),
    solve(N, 1, [], 0).

solve(N, J, Board, Count) when N < J ->
    print(N, Board),
    Count + 1;
solve(N, J, Board, Count) ->
    F = fun(I, Cnt) ->
            case get_data(I, J) of
                true  ->
                    put_data(I, J, false),
                    Cnt2 = solve(N, J+1, [I|Board], Cnt),
                    put_data(I, J, true),
                    Cnt2;
                false -> Cnt
            end
        end,
    lists:foldl(F, Count, lists:seq(1, N)).

put_data(I, J, Bool) ->
    put({row, I  }, Bool),
    put({add, I+J}, Bool),
    put({sub, I-J}, Bool).

get_data(I, J) ->
    get({row, I}) andalso get({add, I+J}) andalso get({sub, I-J}).

print(N, Board) ->
    Frame = "+-" ++ string:copies("--", N) ++ "+",
    io:format("~s~n", [Frame]),
    lists:foreach(fun(I) -> print_line(N, I) end, Board),
    io:format("~s~n", [Frame]).

print_line(N, I) ->
    F = fun(X, S) when X == I -> "Q " ++ S;
           (_, S)             -> ". " ++ S
        end,
    Line = lists:foldl(F, "", lists:seq(1, N)),
    io:format("| ~s|~n", [Line]).
```

and make it executable from linux shell:

```
chmod +x queue
```

And then run it from linux shell with command `./queue` or `time ./queue`

Comment: Of course the measured time then includes the time to start erlang and compile the code, as well as running the actual code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I prefer the second method using escript. But I cannot run it in native mode because of the following error: Warning: this system is not configured for native-code compilation.
escript: exception error: no function clause matching 
                 test__escript__1383__893414__479613:main([]) (./test, line 5)
  in function  escript:run/2 (escript.erl, line 747)
  in call from escript:start/1 (escript.erl, line 277)
  in call from init:start_it/1 
  in call from init:start_em/1 
How can I configure my system to run it in native mode?

Comment: Probably you should create new question.